# Method arguments in C# possible like this?

Tags: c#

I have an assignment from my teacher and I think that the task in not possible but he insists that it can be done: basically I need to create o method WriteSum that adds two integer numbers and the method is called by him in the main method while I must write the WriteSum method code in a class: He insists that the method must be called like this: `WriteSum(22+24)` with return value 46. 
Is this possible??? 
From what I know in C# method arguments are given with commas between them so his correct code for calling the method should be WriteSum(22,24)???

His code is like this:

```
string n = Calculator.WriteSum(22+24);
Console.WriteLine(n);
Console.Read();
```

And I have to write the "WriteSum" method in a class Calculator.

Comment: `WriteSum(22+24)` is the same effect as `WriteSum(46)` since the compiler will probably add up the constants anyway. Maybe the teacher wants it as a string, `WriteSum("22+24")` and you are to parse it? Did you ask your teacher for clarification?

Comment: As lurker said just accept a string split on plus add and return

Comment: Please [edit] to post the relevant code from his main method along with the declaration of the method you need to implement.

Comment: As a clarification, calling `WriteSum(22+24)` the sum is done before the call, and your method does not do any sum. Even more, the method doesn't even know there was an addition, it just receives the number 46. You could call the method also `WriteSum(3*9-4)`, and as you can see there is no sum involved, and it will work just fine because it received an `int`.

Comment: If `WriteSum` accepts a `Expression<Func<int>>` as parameter then it might be possible (`() => 22+24`), but I don't think the teacher has this intention.

Answer (score 5):

You are right: C# will evaluate the expression `22+24` *before* calling your method. In other words, `WriteSum(22+24)` will behave exactly like `WriteSum(46)`, i.e., it will

1. call a single-parameter method with the name `WriteSum` and
2. pass the integer expression `46` as the argument.

---

Thus, the requirements *as stated in your question* cannot be fulfilled. As others have mentioned in the comments, it is possible that your instructor *actually meant* to assign you one of the following tasks:

1. Just write the value of the parameter that has been passed. In that case, however, the method should be called `WriteInt` instead of `WriteSum` and the implementation would be trivial.
2. If the method takes a *string argument* (i.e. `WriteSum("22+24")`), you'd need to parse the string, extract the summands, add them, and print (or return) the result. This *does* sound like a realistic task given to a student.

In any case, you should really clarify the requirements before you start to implement anything.